# How to speed up 3D Ising Model simulation with Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

So I am trying to simulate the 3D Ising Model to generate magnetization values for a given temperature and lattice size using the Wolff Cluster Algorithm. I'm using Python to run all my codes and have used the multiprocessing module to parallelize the whole run. The idea is to run the simulation till equilibrium reaches and start taking samples with autocorrelation time apart.

For a lattice size of 80x80x80 at a temperature of 4.5 (critical temperature), my code is taking around 5 days to complete. When I checked online, the usual time it took to simulate even a 500x500x500 lattice was 3 days but mine is taking longer. I would like to know if there are faster ways to produce magnetization samples. I have attached my code for reference. I used Python because I am new to C++ and it's hard to simulate on that. I would also like to know if there are ML techniques that can be employed in generating these samples, I tried using Mixture Density Networks and it hasn't gotten me very far.

```
import numpy as np 
from collections import deque
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Pool
plt.style.use('ggplot')

SAMPLES = 1000  #No of Independant samples that needs to be generated
AUTO = 20  #Autocorrelation time to get independant samples
LOOP = 10 #The same simulation is done LOOP no of times to get SAMPLES*LOOP no of samples

class Cluster3D:
    
    def __init__(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp   #Sampling temperature
        self.width = 20     #Size of the lattice
        self.state = np.ones((self.width,self.width,self.width), dtype=int)   #Creates a 3D lattice with all spins = +1
        self.length = SAMPLES*AUTO
        self.equi = 500    #The model is made to equilibriate before the samples are taken
        self.p_add = 1 - np.exp(-2/temp)     #Probability with which the clusters are formed
        self.auto = 0
        self.avg_size = 0
        
    def neighboring_sites(self, s):
        w = self.width
        return [((s[0]+1)%w, s[1], s[2]), ((s[0]-1)%w, s[1], s[2]),
                 (s[0], (s[1]+1)%w, s[2]), (s[0], (s[1]-1)%w, s[2]),
                 (s[0], s[1], (s[2]+1)%w), (s[0], s[1], (s[2]-1)%w)]
  
    def cluster_flip(self, seed):
        spin = self.state[seed]
        self.state[seed] = -spin  
        cluster_size = 1
        unvisited = deque([seed])   # use a deque to efficiently track the unvisited cluster sites
        while unvisited:   # while unvisited sites remain
            site = unvisited.pop()  # take one and remove from the unvisited list
            for nbr in self.neighboring_sites(site):
                if self.state[nbr] == spin and np.random.random() < self.p_add:
                    self.state[nbr] = -spin
                    unvisited.appendleft(nbr)
                    cluster_size += 1
        return cluster_size
    
    def wolff_cluster_move(self):
        rng = np.random.default_rng()
        seed = tuple(rng.integers(0,self.width,3))
        return self.cluster_flip(seed)
            
    def compute_magnetization(self):
        return np.sum(self.state)/self.width**3

    def compute_internal_energy(self):
        n = self.width
        l = self.state
        e = 0.0
        for i in range(0,n):
            for j in range(0,n):
                for k in range(0,n):
                    if i+1<=n-1:
                        e += -l[i,j,k]*l[i+1,j,k]
                    if j+1<=n-1:
                        e += -l[i,j,k]*l[i,j+1,k]
                    if k+1<=n-1:
                        e += -l[i,j,k]*l[i,j,k+1]
                    if i-1>=0:
                        e += -l[i,j,k]*l[i-1,j,k]
                    if j-1>=0:
                        e += -l[i,j,k]*l[i,j-1,k]
                    if k-1>=0:
                        e += -l[i,j,k]*l[i,j,k-1]
        return e

    def run_ising_wolff_mcmc(self, n):
        total = 0
        for _ in range(n):
            total += self.wolff_cluster_move()
        return total

    def sample_autocovariance(self, x):
        x_shifted = x - np.mean(x)
        return np.array([np.dot(x_shifted[:len(x)-t],x_shifted[t:])/len(x) 
                         for t in range(self.length)])

    def find_correlation_time(self, autocov):
        smaller = np.where(autocov < np.exp(-1)*autocov[0])[0]
        return smaller[0] if len(smaller) > 0 else len(autocov)

    def do_wolff(self):
        trace = np.zeros(self.length)
        energy = np.zeros(self.length)
        total_flips = 0
        self.run_ising_wolff_mcmc(self.equi)
        for i in range(self.length):    
            total_flips += self.wolff_cluster_move()
            trace[i] = self.compute_magnetization()
            energy[i] = self.compute_internal_energy()
            
        autocov = self.sample_autocovariance(np.abs(trace))
        time = self.find_correlation_time(autocov)
        self.avg_size = total_flips/self.length
        self.auto = time
        
        return trace

def generator(temp):
    state = Cluster3D(temp)
    raw_spins = state.do_wolff()
    nets = [raw_spins[-AUTO*i] for i in range(SAMPLES)]
    return abs(np.array(nets))   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    u1 = time.time()
    temp = 5.0      #Temperature at which the samples are generated
    
    temps = [temp for i in range(LOOP)]
    raw_spin = []
    pool = Pool()
    data = pool.map(generator, temps)     #Runs the algorithm for the same temperature for LOOP no of times across multiple CPU cores
    raw_spin.append(data)
    spins = np.array(data).flatten()    #Size of spins is SAMPLES*LOOP
   
    u2 = time.time()

    print('Time Taken to Simulate - ', abs(u2-u1))
```

Comment: you need to narrow down your problem to bottleneck/s, use `line_profiler` for that (you can take a look at pycharm line profiler extension). Then optimize those bottlenecks. Instead of python loops use either `numpy` vectorizations or `numba` package (for example `compute_internal_energy` function is ideal task for numba)